# Returning address of a local variable error

Tags: c, pointers

I typed this code:

```
void main()
{
    int *a;
    a = foo();
    printf("%d\n", *a);
}

int* foo()
{
    int b = 10;
    return &b;
}
```

After compiling, there were 2 problems:

```
1. error - Conflicting type for foo()
2. warning - function returns address of local variable
```

But then I write this

```
int* foo();
void main()
{
    int *a;
    a = foo();
    printf("%d\n", *a);
}

int* foo()
{
    int b = 10;
    return &b;
}
```

Now, it does not give an error after compiling, which is obvious, but, why does the compiler not give a warning for returning address of local variable?

How does declaring or not declaring a function affects returning address of a local variable?

Sorry for not mentioning before, but I am using GNU GCC compiler

Comment: Which compiler are you using? gcc (mine is 4.8.4) does give a warning about the local variable return address in both cases.

Comment: Same here (Mac OSX - clang-700.1.81): your **second** version of the program causes `warning: address of stack memory associated with local variable 'b' returned [-Wreturn-stack-address]`

Comment: @kaylum I tried his code in codepad.org, it is also **not showing any warning** for the second case.[here](http://codepad.org/HpUwPfmb)

Comment: @jblixr Using an online compiler is not a great idea for this sort of thing. 1. It's not clear that codepad ever actually shows any warnings at all. 2. You don't know what the compile command line is with respect to warnings.

Comment: @kaylum But the first case showed warning.

Comment: @jblixr Hmm, you are right. Interesting. But the question to the OP (and you) is still the same. What compiler is being used? If you want to dig then find out what compiler codepad uses. Any answer will be compiler specific.

Comment: The question is about behaviour of a particular compiler, so you should include your compiler name and version in the question

Comment: Clang gives me two warnings: `warning: return type of 'main' is not 'int' [-Wmain-return-type]` and `warning: address of stack memory associated with local variable 'b' returned [-Wreturn-stack-address]`

Comment: I tried it with mingw ver 3.4.2 and it gives the warning for the second case, even without -Wall `warning: function returns address of local variable`

Comment: I have tried the second program and it does give warning for me in gcc

Comment: Please post one question at a time.

Comment: Please read about function prototypes http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ansi_c/c_using_functions.htm

Answer (score 0):

The C standard does not require compilers to give warnings except for syntax errors.

ISO/IEC 9899:1999, 5.1.1.3:

> A conforming implementation shall produce at least one diagnostic
>   message (identified in an implementation-defined manner) if a
>   preprocessing translation unit or translation unit contains a
>   violation of any syntax rule or constraint, even if the behavior is
>   also explicitly specified as undefined or implementation-defined.
>   Diagnostic messages need not be produced in other circumstances.

The behavior you described is inconsistent (i.e. not nice) but valid/standard-compliant.

Answer (score 0):

Compilers aren't required to give you warnings or errors except for syntax errors. Semantic errors may or may not be detected by a compiler, depending on the circumstances.

Thats extra though and not required by the standard.

In your case the inconsistency is a little unfortunate.

Answer (score -3):

You must declare your function before calling it. In first case you called foo and then you defined it. Try it like this and it should work:

```
int* foo()
{
  int b = 10;
  return &b;
}

void main()
{
  int *a;
  a = foo();
  printf("%d\n", *a);
}
```